# 'X' or 'x' is meant to be used to quit the calculator. I receive the error "primary expected" (c++)

Tags: c++

I am a newbie trying to solve the exercise from chapter 6 of Stroustrup's PPP. Everything works fine but 'X' and 'x'. I enter expressions followed by '=' and I receive correct results, but when I hit 'X' or 'x' to quit the program I receive the error "primary expected". Any idea what am I missing?. I am using GCC 8.3.0, VS Code and 'g++ -o nameofexecutable.exe sourcefile.cpp' to compile. I also use windows 10. Here is my code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

class Token {
public:
    char kind;        
    double value;     
    Token(char ch)    
        :kind(ch), value(0) { }    
    Token(char ch, double val)     
        :kind(ch), value(val) { }
};

class Token_stream {
public: 
    Token_stream();   
    Token get();      
    void putback(Token t);    
private:
    bool full;        
    Token buffer;     
};

// The constructor just sets full to indicate that the buffer is empty:
Token_stream::Token_stream()
:full(false), buffer(0)    
{}

// The putback() member function puts its argument back into the Token_stream's buffer:
void Token_stream::putback(Token t){
    if (full) error("putback() into a full buffer");
    buffer = t;      
    full = true;     
}

Token Token_stream::get(){
    if (full) {      
        full=false;
        return buffer;
    } 

    char ch;
    cin >> ch;    
    switch (ch) {
    case '=':    
    case 'x':    // for "quit" it does not work!
    case 'X':    // for "quit" it does not work!
    case '(': case ')': case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/': case '%':
        return Token(ch);        
    case '.':
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
        {    
            cin.putback(ch);         
            double val;
            cin >> val;              
            return Token('8',val);   
        }
    default:
        error("Bad token");
    }
}

Token_stream ts;        

double expression();    

// deal with numbers and parentheses
double primary()
{
    Token t = ts.get();
    switch (t.kind) {
    case '(':    
        {    
            double d = expression();
            t = ts.get();
            if (t.kind != ')') error("')' expected");
            return d;
        }
    case '8':            // '8' is used to represent a number
        return t.value;  
    default:
        error("primary expected");
    }
}

// deal with *, /, and %
double term()
{
    double left = primary();
    Token t = ts.get();  

    while(true) {
        switch (t.kind) {
        case '*':
            {
            left *= primary();
            t = ts.get();
            break;
            }
        case '/':
            {    
                double d = primary();
                if (d == 0) error("divide by zero");
                left /= d; 
                t = ts.get();
                break;
            }
        case '%':
            {
                int d = primary();
                int l = left;
                if (d == 0) error("divide by zero");
                left = l%d;
                t = ts.get();
                break;
            }
        default: 
            ts.putback(t); 
            return left;
        }
    }
}

// deal with + and -
double expression()
{
    double left = term();  
    Token t = ts.get();    

    while(true) {    
        switch(t.kind) {
        case '+':
            left += term();  
            t = ts.get();
            break;
        case '-':
            left += term();  
            t = ts.get();
            break;
        default: 
            ts.putback(t);   
            return left;     
        }
    }
}

int main()
try
{
    cout << "A simple calculator"<<endl;
    cout << "Floating point numbers are acepted"<<endl;
    cout << "You can use: '+','-','*','/', and '%'" << endl; 
    cout << "Enter X or x to quit" << endl;
    cout << "Use '=' to solve" << endl;
    
    double val;
    while (cin) {
        Token t = ts.get();

        if (t.kind == 'x') break; // 'q' for quit
        if (t.kind == '=')        // ';' for "print now"
            cout << "=" << val << '\n';
        else
            ts.putback(t);
        val = expression();
    }
    keep_window_open();
}
catch (exception& e) {
    cerr << "error: " << e.what() << '\n'; 
    keep_window_open();
    return 1;
}
catch (...) {
    cerr << "Oops: unknown exception!\n"; 
    keep_window_open();
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: Use either `std::toupper` or `std::tolower` so you only have to make one comparison.

Comment: "I receive the error "primary expected"" Well, do you see the part of your code that raises that error message explicitly? Think about how it is positioned within the code (i.e., in the `default:` block of a switch) - what does that imply about what happened? Now, try to work backwards from there. See also https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users .

Comment: You may want to `transform` your input `string` to all lower case or all upper case before processing the input.

Comment: There is only one place where "primary expected" is thrown - in `primary()` when it reads an unrecognized token.  So, if it reads an X, it throws that error. So, maybe you are calling `primary()` at the wrong time? Only your top-level reading loop in `main()` is handling the X, which implies maybe you are typing the X in the middle of another expression?

Comment: "but when I hit 'X' or 'x' to quit the program" In your own words, what part of the program is intended to cause this to happen? What is the behaviour of that part of the code when `X` is typed? What is the behaviour of that part of the code when `x` is typed? (Hint: is `'x'` equal to `'X'`?)

Comment: *" Everything works fine but 'X' and 'x'. "* -- if you remove everything that "works fine", it's easier to focus on the problem. If you drop all the code that should not be invoked when exiting, do you get the same issue? (You could also drop four of your five instruction lines, leaving only `"Enter X or x to quit"`.) If so, then drop it. If not, look into why execution enters a part of the code that it should not enter.

Comment: Yes, that's also a good point. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: An input of just `x` [seems to run fine here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xYoTrvq7a). However, there are a few compiler warnings you should deal with. You should also make sure your input is successful before using it. For example, empty input [currently breaks the program](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aG93Th8eT).

Comment: You need to complete your training with `switch` and `case` by reading up on the `break` statement for `switch/case` statement.

Comment: Thanks to all and sorry for not making a "minimal reproducible example" here.

Comment: Hey chris to be honest I was ignoring the compiler warnings (there are two but now I will try to understand what those warnings are about ,they go like this: "warning: control reaches end of non-void function")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Padawan needs to learn about the `break` statement when using `switch/case`.
The `break` prevents execution from *falling* from one case to the next:

```
char ch;
cin >> ch;    
switch (ch) {
case '=': 
    // Do something for '=';
    break; // exit the case

case 'x':    // for "quit" it does not work!
case 'X':    // for "quit" it does not work!
    return 0; // exit from function.
    // No need for break here since return breaks out of the switch.

case '(': case ')': case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/': case '%':
    return Token(ch);        
    // No need for break here since return breaks out of the switch.

case '.':
case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
    {    
        cin.putback(ch);         
        double val;
        cin >> val;              
        return Token('8',val);   
    }
    // No need for break here since return breaks out of the switch.

default:
    error("Bad token");
}
```

Comment: Hi Thomas I did as you suggested and now it works. As you said, I will go and re-read more about how the break statement works when using switch/case. Thanks.